# How to identify the difference between file and folder ondropping in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I have a container which allows dropping of files and folder. I want to identify the **drop item type( file or folder )** and the exact **folder or file path of dropped item**.

Note: I am able to get item details if I use **webkitGetAsEntry()** but I don't want to use this.

Someone suggested me to use files[0].size == 4096 ( for identifying folder) and its not giving exactly 4096. Its varying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can may help. It can be improved but do the job:

```
function drop_type(string)
{
    return /(\.[a-z0-9]{2,5})$/i.test(string) ? 'file' : 'directory';
}
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xd2mazt0/).

This is dirty solution but works. In regex you can add extensions and match it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check folder using `if (!f.type && f.size % 4096 == 0)` for folder detection. Please see below snippet.

```js
function handleDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        folders = 0,
        other = 0;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { // iterate in the files dropped
        if (!f.type && f.size % 4096 == 0) folders++;
        else other++;
    }
    
    if (folders && !other) {
        if (folders > 1) info.innerHTML = 'You dropped ' + folders +' folders!';
        else info.innerHTML = 'You dropped 1 folder!';
    } else if (!folders && other) {
        if (other > 1) info.innerHTML = 'You dropped ' + other +' files!';
        else info.innerHTML = 'You dropped 1 file!';
    } else {
        if (folders > 1) info.innerHTML = 'You dropped ' + folders +' folders ';
        else info.innerHTML = 'You dropped 1 folder ';
        if (other > 1) info.innerHTML += 'and ' + other +' files!';
        else info.innerHTML += 'and 1 file!';
    }
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    info.innerHTML = '<b>Dragging...</b>';
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    info.innerHTML = '';
}

var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone'),
    info = document.getElementById('info');

dropZone.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

```css
#drop_zone {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #bbb;
}
#info {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: This check falsely categorizes files without extension and where size is a multiple of 4096 bytes as folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which I used. ( also supports IE11)

**JS function**

```
    function isFile(file, callback) {
    var start = 0; //start byte
    var stop = 4; // end byte - to avoid read all the content
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            var binary = "";
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
            var length = bytes.byteLength;
            if (length == 0) {
                callback(false);
            } else {
                callback(true);
            }
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    };
    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

**usage**

```
    isFile(file, function (e) {
        alert( e ? "It's a File": "Nope ! It's a Folder");
    });
```

working example : https://jsfiddle.net/rukshanf/t9uxbkc0/